# unrecognized function Nn in R

Tags: r

I am learning R package *SimInf* to simulate data-driven stochastic epidemiological models. As I was reading the documentation I came across an unrecognized funcion `Nn` when defining a function for epicurves. Specifically, this line:

```
j <- sample(seq_len(Nn(model)), 1)
```

Values of ***model***  are integers. My guess is that `Nn` selects non-negative values, however my R does not recognize this function. From documentation it does not look like they pre-defined `Nn` either. Can someone please tell if they know what "Nn" is for? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to go is always taking the package-name and triple-":" it, such that you can find nearly all functions inside the package. Maybe you are familiar with namespacing a function via `packageName::functionFrompackageTocall`. The `packageName:::` shows (nearly) all functions defined in this package. If you do this in R-Studio with `SimInf::` and `SimInf:::`, you will see that the latter gives much more functions. But you can only find the functions `SimInf:::Nd` and `SimInf:::Nc`, not the `Nn`-function. Hence you will have to go to the github-sources of the package, in this case https://github.com/stewid/SimInf .Then search for `Nn` the whole repository. You will see that it seems like it is always an `int`, but this doesn't help you since you want to get ii as a function, not as a variable. Scrolling further down in the search-results, you will find the `NEWS.md`-file which mentions `The 'Nn' function to determine the number of nodes in a model has been replaced with the S4 method 'n_nodes'.` in the https://github.com/stewid/SimInf/blob/fd7eb4a29b82a4a97f64b528bb0e78e5474aa8a5/NEWS.md file under `SimInf 8.0.0 (2020-09-13)`. Hence having a current version of `SimInf` installed, it shouldn't use the method `Nn` anymore. If you use it in your code, replace it by `n_nodes`. If you find it in current package code, you can email the package-maintainer that you found a bug in his code.

TLDR: `Nn` is an outdated version of `n_nodes`